# Is the length of array using JavaScript [] literal really reflecting its physical size in memory?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In JavaScript, there are two ways to define an array:

```
var array = new Array(); // which is not preferred
```

and

```
var array = [];
```

[Edited to correct misconception]
In fact, no matter I am using [] or new Array(), they are always object because we can define

```
var object = [];
object["key"] = "value";
console.log(object.key); // gives "value"
```

I would like to know if I define an "array" using [], what would be the physical size if I have the following code:

```
var array = [];
array[1000] = "value";
```

If it behaves like an object, the physical size of it should only be consisted of the key-value pair [1000]->"value". However, if I output the length attribute of the array using `console.log(array.length);`, it gives 1001 as if there are 1000 elements before the [1000]->"value" I just inserted.

So what should be the physical size in memory of the "array" defined using []?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. `[]` is an array. Your counterexample is meaningless because you can also do: `var array = new Array(); array["key"] = "value"; console.log(array.key);` and algo get `value` printed. Also, JavaScript arrays are not kept in contiguous memory. if you want that, use an `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: All Arrays regardless of their inception are just glorified objects

Comment: Does it means that no matter I am using [] or new Array(), they are all just an illusion and the data structure behind them are always object?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: Worth reading [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) if you haven't already. It explains much (if not all) of what you are asking.

Comment: And as you have mentioned since JavaScripts arrays are not kept in contiguous memory, so no matter I assign a value to `array[1000]` or `array[10]`, they are occupying the same physical size in the memory?

Comment: Memory use is handled behind the scene in Javascript and the developer has no knowledge or control over it, not like with `C` or other languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your terminology "physical size" is unclear. Do you mean "the number of defined elements in the array"? You use another unclear term which is "actual size".

An array (however created) has the following characteristics with regard to its "size":

1. **`length`**. This is the index of the last element which contains a value plus one.
2. **Number of defined elements**. This is less than or equal to length. You could find it by doing something like `array.reduce(function(n) { return n+1; }, 0)`, since `reduce` skips over undefined elements. `filter` does too, so you could also do `array.filter(function() { return true; }).length`.
3. **Internal size**. As a commenter mentioned, this is engine-specific, and there's no way, or reason, for you to see this. Different engines have different strategies for managing the internal representation of arrays, and furthermore they might switch between strategies. So one array might be represented as a contiguous block of memory locations, but then, when it reached a particular degree of sparseness, might change its representation to one more suited for a sparse array. It might pre-allocate chunks of memory if it thinks that the array might be growing. Therefore, there is no way to know (or reason to care) that two arrays are "occupying the same physical size in the memory".

On another topic, you seem to be getting hung up on the distinction between arrays vs. objects. `[]` and `new Array()` are very much arrays. They are exactly arrays. However, in JS, arrays inherit all object behavior. To put it another way, arrays are a special kind of object, which provide features such as automatic management of `length`, and their own prototype methods.

Comment: edited to better reflect what I mean for "size", thanks.
I think the "internal size" is better reflecting what I mean for size. The reason I ask about the internal size is mainly concerning the performance issue. For example, if one engine represents array using contiguous memory. That would mean If I assign value to `array[1000]`, then 1000 "useless" elements will be inserted ahead into the memory. If the index is bigger, that may become an issue in some old computers

Comment: As has been said countless times here on SO, and elsewhere, you optimize when you need to optimize. You worry about performance when you need to worry about performance. Today's JS engines are **highly** optimized. It's almost never worthwhile trying to  guess how they are doing things and somehow code around your guess, which will usually be wrong, or irrelevant. You can use sparse arrays to your heart's content--make an array with one element at position one hundred million--and performance will be just fine.

Comment: *make an array with one element at position one hundred million--and performance will be just fine.* However, you would not want to iterate over this array, even with `forEach` and its friends.

Answer (score 0):

From [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) - `The length property represents an unsigned, 32-bit integer that is always numerically greater than the highest index in the array.`

For the element size there is no direct method to call, but you can do determine size using filter -

```
array.filter(function(value) { return value !== undefined }).length
```

```js
var array = [];
array[1000] = "value";

alert(array.filter(function(value) { return value !== undefined }).length);
```

Comment: Your first 2 lines are a bit confusing. You state that Array.length returns the highest index (which is wrong, it returns the length, which will be 1 integer higher than the highest index) but then literally quote the doc saying that your first line is wrong.

Comment: `From doc`, what is the source? As of ES6, this value is (2^53)-1 (also know as Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: Your suggestion for using `filter` to find the "element size", which I guess means the number of defined elements, could be tweaked a bit. `filter` by definition will skip over holes, so the only case in which the callback will return false is that where the element **is** present, but with an explicit value of undefined, which arguably **should** be included in the "size". I think `array.filter(function() { return true; })` is closer to what you probably want.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

 @Xotic750

Comment: can you provide a reference where it says array length is Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER @@Xotic750
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As of ES6, values supplied as a `length` are converted with the abstract [`ToLength`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tolength), you see in the specification (2^53)-1. Now look at [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.max_safe_integer), you will also see (2^53)-1. Now look at a method of `Array`, let's choose [`forEach`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.foreach) as an example, see the abstract `ToLength` in its specification?

Answer (score 0):

The `.length` property is the only really special thing about arrays, and its value is always 1 more than the largest numerical property set. I.e. `arr.foo = 'bar'` does not influence the `.length` property, but `arr[100] = 'bar'` does. Both assignment operations are fundamentally doing the same thing though, they're setting a property on an object.

The `.length` property is only really there to allow you to iterate the array using `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`, otherwise there'd be no way for you to know when to stop the iteration. You are expected to manipulate the array using `.push` and `.pop` and such which ensure that indices are contiguous, or otherwise keep indices sane; if you do, `.length` pointing to the highest numerical index plus 1 is exactly the only needed behavior.

However, Javascript arrays are fundamentally just sparse objects, and you can do with them whatever you want, as long as you're aware of this behavior.

Comment: To be pedantic, another special thing about arrays is their prototype methods.

Answer (score -1):

You start off with some weird presumptions. Yes, Arrays are objects...just like just about everything in JS is. You could think of it as a class that extends object with its own functionality on top of object. That doesn't make it any less of an Array.

And the Array is NOT simply key/value pairs when it comes to its indices. That's what makes it an Array. If you put something at index 1000 then it will need to make indices 0-1000 for that Array to have that index. So yes, it is well expected that if you assign a value at `arr[1000]` there's suddenly going to be 1001 total indices (1001 since it indexes from 0).

This is true regardless of the syntax you use to create the Array object. Either syntax still creates the same type of Array object...it's just different syntax for doing so. The only reason some people avoid `new Array()` is because if you give only a single argument of a positive integer it assumes you mean that you want to make that many empty indices, and some people find that confusing. Again, that's just syntax though...

---

**To Detractors**: When you set index 1000 you can `pop()` it off then end and *still have 999 as the highest index, even though it's undefined*. Regardless of whether values have been set for all those indices, as far as the Array is concerned when you set index 1000 you created indices 0-1000, and it will treat those as actual indices in the Array, requiring you to utilize Array methods to remove them from the Array. The fact that 0-999 have undefined values does not change that as far as the Array is concerned.

Comment: "It has to make indices 0-1000"‽ Well, it doesn't actually "make" those indices.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I take minor issue with your statement that "it will need to make indices 0-1000". I'm not quite sure what you mean by "make indices", but if you mean allocating memory, that would **not** happen in almost any engine. Engines specifically manage sparse array cases.

Comment: @deceze @torazaburo - Make an empty array, set index 1000 to something...then call `pop()` on it. Check the length before and after. It will be 1001, then 1000. The removal of index 1000 doesn't make it 0 length again...so index 999 is very real to it once index 1000 is set. As far as the Array is concerned there are 1001 actual total indices within itself once the index 1000 is set. The fact that it doesn't assign each of the VALUES does not change the fact that it now considers them indices within the Array.

Comment: [...continued] You would have to use Array methods to remove all those indices to get it back down in length, regardless of the fact that they are all undefined. As far as the Array is concerned you just implicitly made indices 0-1000 when you set `arr[1000]`

Comment: `.length` simply decreases by 1 upon `.pop`; it doesn't re-traverse the entire array to figure out which indices are set (that would make `.pop` extremely costly). The `.length` property operates on some very simple and imperfect rules. That still doesn't mean all those `undefined` indices "actually exist".

Comment: @deceze - The fact that they don't take up memory does not change their "existence" to the Array. If I pop off index 1000 and it considers 999 the next one then as far as the Array is concerned, 999 exists. And on top of that, **there definitely are times where it actually does traverse all that**. For example, when slicing the Array. Hence why making a slice off an array that is 10 indices in length happens significantly faster than one that is a billion indices in length even when only the last index has a value, hence this benchmark here: https://jsfiddle.net/ce74avvm/

Comment: That's all due to the behavior and existence of the `.length` property, which is just a number which increments and decrements on certain array operations. JavaScript does not actually populate all indices or reserve memory, it simply behaves that way in userland code because of `.length` and every operation that logically hangs on it.

Comment: @deceze - The fact that it doesn't require memory to be allocated does not change the end behavior. If I wrote an engine that allocated memory for those indices internally and still acted the EXACT SAME externally would it be any less a JS engine? In fact, many languages do require memory be allocated for all indices of an Array. That Array behaves with index 999 being considered part of it. That simple. As far as the Array behavior is concerned, 999 is a part of the Array with an undefined value. The fact that it accomplishes that without using specific memory for it doesn't change that.

Comment: There's a difference between index 999 being set and holding the value `undefined` and index 999 not existing and evaluating to `undefined` upon access.

Comment: @deceze - deceze...you're describing how an **implentation/engine** of JS would typically work inside. JS (or more accurately ECMAScript) is a spec which defines, as you put it, _userland_. If a clever implementation somehow got prototype inheritance to work without allocating separate memory for each object's prototype would that somehow make the explanation that JS has a prototype for each object less accurate? It would not. In JS the required behavior makes the implementation, not the other way around. Even you state that my description is accurate for userland, and that's what JS **is**.

Comment: ...continued... and in JS the language what you just said isn't true. JS does not care if the engine sets each index between 0 and length to undefined explicitly or evaluates it upon access. The userland behavior is what JS is...and JS behaves as if 999 is a part of the Array, considering it the next last index after 1000 is popped off, regardless of how the implementation deals with that internally.

Comment: There *is* a discernible difference in userland: `.hasOwnProperty`. Therefore a nuanced explanation of `.length` is necessary; you're oversimplifying it.

Comment: @deceze - actually the spec on Array never once specifies anything about hasOwnProperty's operation on Array indices. It does, however, specify behaviors such as the fact that `array.slice(-2);` is going to return a new Array of the last 2 elements in `array`, and in our example that means 999 is a very real part of that, and must be included in that return for the spec to work.

Comment: As far as "oversimplifying" goes, I'd have to counter that "existence as a construct is predicated on whether or not memory is allocated" is about as much of an "oversimplification" as there can be in a spec :) There is a very real concept in the spec that 999 is the 2nd to last element in the array. It "exists" in that manner.